# How to find users with common tags in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm sorry if this question has been asked in some way already but I couldn't find what I was looking for. If it does exist don't hesitate to mark this as a duplicate.

I have a database with a tagging system. I use two tables for this tagging system:

```
tags(id, tag)
user_tags(id, username, tag_id)
```

Every time a new tag is created it is given an id number (I check to make sure the tag does not already exist before creating a new tag). I then attach this tag to the user that has created it or has added it to their profile by associating the tag's id with their username.

What I want to do is to take two usernames and find all of the tag_ids they have in common. I'm accessing my database with Node.js and I'm not really sure how to query this. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: That's the easy bit! Anyway, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Note that id in user_tags serves no useful purpose. But username would more typically be user_id - on the understanding that a user may want to change their name.